# Visual Studio and barcode scanner not working in debug mode

Tags: c#, winforms, barcode-scanner

When I run even the simplest WinForm application (C#) in Visual Studio 2013, let's say a form with just one textbox on it, I can not get the barcode scanner to output the barcode information to the textbox.

Now, this is true if I am running the application either in debug mode (F5) or in the mode "start without debugging" (Ctrl-F5)

HOWEVER, if I run the actual executable, say by going to the windows folder and to the Debug directory and running WindowsFormsApplication3.exe then the barcode scans in fine.

This happens in all projects.

I am using the SerialMagic Professional Windows Desktop Version 5.6.0.7 as my wedge software.

The wedge software works on all other inputs (email, Word, Excel, etc.)  The only limitation I am finding is trying to work with the barcode scanner in an development environment under Visual Studio control

Any thoughts?

Comment: Sounds like it finds the window (for example a TextBox control) that it should simulate input to by searching through the windows that currently exist on the screen, and that the way it does that is not compatible with you running one program under another, in this case Visual Studio. Maybe it's trying to find the window in Visual Studio? Anyway, this sounds like something more for the support services of the company that makes the software.

Comment: @RenniePet  -- Thanks for the thoughts.  That really helps me understand what could be occurring!